# How do "hits" impact Lucene search performance?

Tags: performance, lucene

The search API of Lucene receives "hitsPerPage" parameter. It looks like it has significant impact on the search performance. I tried to reduce it from 100 to 10, for instance, and saw the search time decreased twice.

Is it OK? Why does it impact the search performance? Does it indicate any problem?

Comment: Where exactly do you have a hitsPerPage parameter on Lucene?  The number of hits should not really matter as Lucene still needs to score all possible matches. Unless you're writing your own Collector.  
The number of matches should affect memory allocation, and slow you down if you're loading stored fields for all returned documents.

Comment: @GiliNachum I use it to create a `Collector`. What you say is exactly what I am  thinking. Lucene process _all_ matches to sort them by score regardless `histPerPage`, so it should not affect the search performance.

Comment: It affects memory allocation due the size of PriorityQueue used for sorting docId/score pairs. In addition, as mentioned, if you retrieve stored fields, it affects too.

Answer (score 1):

`hitsPerPage` specifies the size of a page, so to speak. Think about it like a Google search result: you can specify the number of results (a "hit") you get on each page.

If you only want `hitsPerPage` hits, that's fine, but if you want more than that, you'll have to retrieve more pages.

> Why it should impact the search performance?

Because Lucene can get away with doing less work (by returning fewer matcher documents) when you want smaller pages. More hits means retrieving more documents, which in turn means seeking more locations in more files.

Comment: Thanks. I retrieve only the 1st page. Now I wonder, why it should impact the search performance.